# ORACLE Match and select two rows by string and date

Tags: sql, oracle

In my oracle database I got a table containing several rows which store event information messages.

Each event is a specific event typ. Further each event has a column value "OPEN" or "CLOSED" which indicates if the event message was an opening or closing message.

Now I need to determine all "OPEN" messages and get the corresponding "CLOSED". My Table for example:

```
    +----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| ID | SENDERID | EventType | EventDescription  | Date                        | Status |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 1  | 111      | EventTyp2 | Something happend | 27.03.17 12:56:10,000000000 | CLOSED |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 2  | 111      | EventTyp1 | Something happend | 20.03.17 00:12:29,666000000 | CLOSED |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 3  | 111      | EventTyp2 | Something happend | 19.03.17 00:12:31,255000000 | OPEN   |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 4  | 222      | EventTyp2 | Something happend | 19.03.17 00:12:31,255000000 | CLOSED |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 5  | 111      | EventTyp1 | Something happend | 17.03.17 11:32:42,452000000 | OPEN   |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 6  | 222      | EventTyp2 | Something happend | 17.03.17 11:32:36,185000000 | OPEN   |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
```

Is there a way to achive a result which returns the eventtyp and description in one row together with the open and closed date?

Im missing how to say "search the CLOSING row which contains the same EventTyp and the 'nearest' date because this must be the closing event message'.

**EDIT**:

Result should like the following example

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID | Sender ID | EventType | EventDescription  | Date Open                   | Date Closed                 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 111       | EventTyp2 | Something happend | 19.03.17 00:12:31,255000000 | 27.03.17 12:56:10,000000000 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2  | 111       | EventTyp1 | Something happend | 17.03.17 11:32:42,452000000 | 20.03.17 00:12:29,666000000 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 3  | 222       | EventTyp2 | Something happend | 17.03.17 11:32:36,185000000 | 19.03.17 00:12:31,255000000 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I've tried the following but as you can asume I get all matched "CLOSED" rows for one "OPEN" row. (I've anonymized the query)

```
WITH EventOpen AS
(
SELECT 
  event.ID,
  event.SENDERID,
  event.DATE,
  event.STATUS,
  event.EVENTTYPID,
  event.EVENTDESCRIPTION
FROM
  EVENTTABLE event 
WHERE
  event.STATUS = 'OPEN'
),
EventClose AS
(
SELECT 
  event.ID,
  event.SENDERID,
  event.DATE,
  event.STATUS,
  event.EVENTTYPID,
  event.EVENTDESCRIPTION
FROM
  EVENTTABLE event
WHERE
  event.STATUS = 'CLOSED'
),

SELECT 
  eo.ID,
  eo.SENDERID
  eo.EVENTDESCRIPTION
  eo.EVENTTYPID
  eo.DATE AS OPENEDAT,  
  ec.DATE AS CLOSEDAD,
FROM 
  EventOpen eo
LEFT OUTER JOIN EventClose ec 
ON eo.EVENTTYPID = ec.EVENTTYPID 
AND eo.SENDERID = ec.SENDERID
AND eo.ID < ec.ID AND (eo.DATE < ec.DATE)
```

**EDIT2:**
Thanks to anonymizing I missed an important column: the senderid. Every event has a specific source which is defined by the senderid

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Can 2 events of the same type overlap in time? In other words - can there simultaneously exist two or more events of the same type?

Comment: Events in case of EVENTTYPID can overlap. The combination of SENDERID and EVENTTYPID can not overlap. Missed the detail about the SENDERID and added this to the inital post.

Comment: Can you have an open followed by two closes?  Or two adjacent opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lead()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) analytic function to match OPEN and CLOSE events:

```
select *
from (
    select
        ev.EVENTTYPID,
        ev.SENDERID,
        ev.DATE open_date,
        lead(ev.DATE) over 
            (partition by ev.EVENTTYPID, ev.SENDERID order by ev.DATE) close_date,
        ev.EVENTDESCRIPTION open_description,       
        lead(ev.EVENTDESCRIPTION) over 
            (partition by ev.EVENTTYPID, ev.SENDERID order by ev.DATE) close_description,
        ev.STATUS
    from EVENTTABLE ev
    ) 
where STATUS = 'OPEN'
order by open_date
```

If you don't want to query events that have not been closed yet - add

```
and close_date is not null
```

to outer `where` clause.

Comment: Nice use case for `lead`, leads to plus one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of variation on the nice solution of @fen1x that covers the case of duplicated OPEN events.

In addition the lead `state` is checked and tested on `CLOSE` ) i.e. processing was closed= or `NULL` (i.e. processing still in progress). The duplicated case of the state `OPEN` is supressed.

```
select 
EVENTTYPE, SENDERID, OPEN_DATE, CLOSE_DATE, OPEN_DESCRIPTION, CLOSE_DESCRIPTION, NEXT_STATUS
from (
    select
        ev.EVENTTYPE,
        ev.SENDERID,
        ev.trans_d open_date,
        lead(ev.trans_d) over 
            (partition by ev.EVENTTYPE, ev.SENDERID order by ev.trans_d) close_date ,
        -- check for duplicated close
        lead(ev.status) over 
            (partition by ev.EVENTTYPE, ev.SENDERID order by ev.trans_d) next_status,
        ev.EVENTDESCRIPTION open_description,       
        lead(ev.EVENTDESCRIPTION) over 
            (partition by ev.EVENTTYPE, ev.SENDERID order by ev.trans_d) close_description, 
        ev.STATUS
    from tab ev
    ) 
where STATUS = 'OPEN' and  (NEXT_STATUS = 'CLOSED' or NEXT_STATUS is NULL)
order by open_date
```

Note that this is the simples cleaning; in case of dups within `EVENTTYPE` and `SENDERID` the last `OPEN` is connected with the first `CLOSE` - all other duplicated events are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

this run on SQL SERVER, should be useful in ORACLE too

```
select position = DENSE_RANK () over (order by EventType, SenderID, Date),*
into #t
from EVENTTABLE event 
where Status ='OPEN'
order by EventType, SenderID, Date

select t.*, CloseDate = ev.DatE
from #t t
    left join EVENTTABLE ev on
        ev.EventType = t.EventType and 
        ev.SenderID = t.SenderID and
        ev.Status = 'OUT' and
        ev.Date > t.Date and
        ev.Date < (select Date from #t where position = t.position+1)
```

Comment: In Oracle the `#t` temp table would probably become a WITH clause (CTE) in the main query.